# How to insert elements at a given position in a two-dimensional array, taking these elements from a list [Python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

My problem:

```
words ＝['a','b','c','d']
table ＝　[['','','']['','','']['','','']['','','']]
```

What I want to obtain [possibly without using numpy library]:

```
table ＝　[['a','','']['b','','']['c','','']['d','','']]
```

How I am trying to do it:

```
#a
for row in range(4):
    for word in words:
        table[row][0] = [w for w in words]

[output]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], '', ''],
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], '', ''],
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], '', ''],
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], '', '']]

#b
for row in range(4):
    for word in words:
        table[row][0] = word

[output]
[['a', '', ''],
 ['a', '', ''],
 ['a', '', ''],
 ['a', '', '']]

#c
for row in range(4):
    table[row][0] = [word for w in words]

[output]
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], '', ''],
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], '', ''],
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], '', ''],
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], '', '']]
```

Is there a way to do it without numpy library? 
Or is it just better to do it with numpy library?
I also tried table.append(word) but did not get the right output.

Comment: Define "better"?

Comment: better = doing it without numpy library is just a waste of time

Comment: `[[word] + row[1:] for word, row in zip(words, table)]`

Comment: @Chris_Rands your code is the answer to my problem, thank you. Can you explain me why in my #b code the loop "for word in words" does not actually loop through the list and always returns the first element of the list?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple list comprehension:

```
words = ['a','b','c','d']

table = [[i, '', ''] for i in words]

# [['a', '', ''], ['b', '', ''], ['c', '', ''], ['d', '', '']]
```

Comment: would this work even if I already have a matrix and want to change those elements at that exact position?

Comment: Need a bit more information, e.g. what is "a matrix" [you mean a `numpy` array?], what syntax do you intend to use to "change the position", what do you even mean by "change the position"?

Comment: would this work even if I already have a 2d-array and want to change 2d-array[['a','','']['a','','']['a','','']] into 2d-array[['b','','']['b','','']['b','','']]?

Comment: No, this solution creates a new array. If you want to population an array with items, I advise `numpy`. You can do this via list of lists, but it will be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:-**

```
words =  ['a','b','c','d']
table = [['','',''],['','',''],['','',''],['','','']]
ls = [list(x)+y[1:] for x,y in zip(words,table)]
print(ls)
```

**Output**

```
[['a', '', ''], ['b', '', ''], ['c', '', ''], ['d', '', '']]
```

Comment: With lists such as ['python','example'], the output of this code would be [['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n'], ['e', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e']]